# How to pass the data from database to view using script with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

In my **HR SYSTEM** i have a button to user **punch-in** and **punch-out** im using **same button** for that. and to enter time also same form im using MODAL in that modal i have a form with **time field** time field can't edit anyone.
My requirement is when user punch-out in that MODAL need to show working hours for that day i tried but i don't know how to pass the **in_time**

```
AttendanceAdapter.method('showPunchDialogShowPunchSuccessCallBack', function(callBackData) {
    this.punch = callBackData;
    $('#PunchModel').modal('show');
    if(this.punch == null){
        $('#PunchModel').find("h3").html("Punch Time-in");
        $('#PunchModel').find("h2");
        modJs.renderForm();
        var d = new Date();
        var x = d.getTime();
        var c =  d.setHours(8,30,0,0); 
        var val = (x-c)/3600000;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val.toFixed(2) ;
    }else{
        $('#PunchModel').find("h3").html("Punch Time-out");
        $('#PunchModel').find("h2");
        modJs.renderForm();
        var d = new Date();
        var x = d.getTime();
        var c =  //here i have to get in_time from  my database
        var val = (x-c)/3600000;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val.toFixed(2) ;

        }   

    var picker = $('#time_datetime').data('datetimepicker');
    picker.setLocalDate(new Date());
});
```

here i have my full script page [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByoLPyyQ3jAjRjRzM25VZXhvT1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: why don't you use ajax and a loading image to indicate loading...

Comment: its already build system so i don't know how to move.....